# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I tried to invoke lambda function with Amazon RDS Postgres database. I got this error, when I tried to run the lambda function:

```json
    {
      "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named'psycopg2._psycopg'",
      "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
      "requestId": "c1c7e814-9560-4d5e-a71d-fa39fc33132e",
      "stackTrace": []
    }
```

[image]

I already add `psycopy2-binary` pack with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "add psycopg2 pack"? Did you package it as a Zip with your source code, or perhaps add it as a Lambda Layer? Example: [Example of Deploying psycopg2-binary Python package as an AWS Lambda Layer | by Bill Glennon | AWS Tip](https://awstip.com/example-of-deploying-of-psycopg2-binary-python-package-as-an-aws-lambda-layer-aef4953ed8d4)

Answer (score 1):

Type the following code line by line into the terminal at the bottom. The pip install pandas command can be replaced with a package of your choosing. You can also install more than 1 package*.

```html
mkdir folder
cd folder
virtualenv v-env
source ./v-env/bin/activate
pip3 install psycopg2
deactivate
```

Then type the following code line by line to create your layer

```html
mkdir python
cd python
cp -r ../v-env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/* .
cd ..
zip -r psycopg2_layer.zip python
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name psycopg2 --zip-file fileb://psycopg2_layer.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.7
```

Please refer below link for postgres layer:-
https://towardsdatascience.com/python-packages-in-aws-lambda-made-easy-8fbc78520e30

[image]

[image]

Go to AWS Lambda function -> create layer
[image]

```html
import psycopg2

db_endpoint = 'RDS-endpoint'
db_port = 5432
db_username = 'RDS-username'
db_password = 'RDS-password'
db_name = 'RDS-DB-name'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  connection = psycopg2.connect(user=db_username, password=db_password, host=db_endpoint, database=db_name)
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  query = "SELECT version() AS version"
  cursor.execute(query)
  results = cursor.fetchone()
  print("results-----",results)
  cursor.close()
  connection.commit()
  return results
```